# MongoDB Write performance issue in Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am facing  some performance issue while writing the data into MongoDB cluster(1Master,1Config , 2 Shards) that we have set.
For 1GB of data(8 Million documents) it is taking more than 30 min while in single node it was taking 8min for that same data.
Here are the config details of VMs:

```
Master  Server – 7GB RAM, 3CPUs.
Config Server    -  1GB RAM, 1CPU.
2 Shard servers-  2GB RAM, 2 CPUs (each shard)
```

All servers configured in Virtual Machines.

Please let me know if you have any idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: What `writeconcern` are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your secondary servers are struggling to keep up with the data writes on the primary, most likely because the have a lower hardware spec. If it is acceptable, you should set the write concern to:

`{ w: 1,j: 1}`

This will allow the secondary servers to temporarily lag behind while you are uploading the data.

Comment: Thanks Jaco, I'm using mongoimport to import data. how to use write concern?

Comment: You can use the option --write concern <document> with  the document specified in my answer.

Comment: I tried this but didn't find any difference. Still it is taking too much time to import.

Comment: What storage engine are you using? And what is your network speed?

Comment: I am using MMAPV1 storage engine. Cluster setup done in LAN, I'm not sure how to check the speed but it would be having fair bandwidth.